# VBA Saving delay after data entry

Tags: excel, vba, save, data-entry

VBA newbie here. I am looking for a way that will allow my excel file to automatically save after a delay of 1 min after data input.

**For example:**

```
User Inputs Data --> Timer Starts (1min)
```

5 seconds passes.

```
User inputs Data --> Timer Restarts (1min)
```

1 min passes.

Excel File Saves - until the user starts inputting data again

Any thoughts?

Comment: That is good, so what is your question?

Comment: The question is not clear. What is 1 minute inside the bracket ? Also let us know what have you tried to achieve the expected output (any code snippet or other details of your try)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to leverage the [Workbook.SheetChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetchange) event and [`Application.OnTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime). You'll also need a `Public` variable, `ScheduledTime` in the example below.

Every time any (non-chart) sheet is changed (e.g. via data entry):

1. Any previously scheduled save, as long as it's still within the one-minute window, is cancelled.
2. A new save is scheduled for one minute out.

---

So something like the following:

In the `ThisWorkbook` code module:

```
Option Explicit

Public ScheduledTime

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _
 ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=ScheduledTime, Procedure:="SaveTheFile", Schedule:=False
    On Error GoTo 0

    ScheduledTime = Now + TimeValue("00:01:00")
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=ScheduledTime, Procedure:="SaveTheFile"
End Sub
```

In a regular code module:

```
Public Sub SaveTheFile()
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

---

You could just as well use the [Worksheet Change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event if you want to restrict this to a particular sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar take on this to BigBen.

In `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Option Explicit

Public SnapShot As String

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    StartTimer
End Sub

Sub StartTimer()
    If SnapShot = vbNullString Then SnapShot = Now
    If DateDiff("s", SnapShot, VBA.CStr(Now)) >= 10 Then ThisWorkbook.Save
    RestartTimer
End Sub

Sub RestartTimer()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "ThisWorkbook.StartTimer"
End Sub
```

And then in the worksheet you are monitoring:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ThisWorkbook.SnapShot = Now
End Sub
```